# @ManagedProperty injected AFTER @PostConstruct

Tags: jsf-2, annotations, myfaces, managed-bean

THIS PROBLEM IS ALREADY SOLVED IN THE MYFACES 2.1 IMPLEMENTATION

I have a link which passes an Integer parameter properly like this:

```
<h:link outcome="/process/createProcess">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{process.idprocess}" />
    Edit
</h:link>
```

It goes to "createProcess.xhtml?id=21" properly, and I have this code in the request scope backing Bean createProcess:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.id}")
private Integer idProcess;

private Process newProcess;

@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
    log();
    if (idProcess!=null)
        newProcess = Dao.getProcessDAO().get(idProcess);
    else
        newProcess = new Process();
}
```

I've notice that `idProcess` is always null. After debugging I realized that setIdProcess method is called **AFTER** `@PostConstruct`.

I understand that injection is done just after the construction of the bean and all the managedProperties are available in `@PostConstruct`.

What am I missing?

Comment: This should not happen. Cannot reproduce this on Mojarra 2.1.1 as well. What JSF impl/version exactly are you using?

Comment: @BalusC Apache MyFaces 2.0 on Tomcat 7.0.  I've read your articles in your blog and your answers here where you said that the injected variables should be available in @postconstruct, but not for me...

Comment: I don't do MyFaces. In future MyFaces questions, please tag as such. I've added it on this question. All I can suggest is to try Mojarra. Even though it's just for testing to exclude one and other so that you can writeup a proper issue report to the MyFaces guys.

Comment: I updated the project to MyFaces 2.1 and now it inject first the variables and then call the @PostConstruct. Finally it was a bug already fixed in the lastest version (June 11). @BalusC Thanks for your advices, i'll take that in account.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, I think the issue in this post is [MYFACES-3116](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3116), with was already fixed at , so 2.0.6, 2.1.0 and upper versions does not have it.