# @URLAction is not called

Tags: jsf, prettyfaces

I have a problem hitting to load method when the page loads/refreshes, page loads correctly from xhtml file, but load method is **never** get called. Any ideas?

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped

@URLMapping(id = "deactivate", pattern = "/deactivateaccount", viewId = "/deactivateaccount.xhtml")
public class DeactivateAccount{

 @URLAction
 public void load(){

     //This method does not hit when page loads 
  }
}
```

Comment: @BalusC do you have ideas what might be wrong in the code?

Comment: I do not use PrettyFaces and I usually only answer from top of head. If I can't answer from top of head, I'll ignore the question. Only if there's a nice bounty and the time allows it, I'll maybe take the effort to look in documentation and source code and tryout for you.

Comment: @Spring: So you say if you enter "/deactivateaccount" in your browser address bar, the load() method isn't invoked?

Comment: @chkal yes! not called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that same mapping id used somewhere else, and it was crashing silently while server starts

Comment: Gotcha. We could probably do a better job of validating this scenario.

Comment: @Lincoln good to see someone from ocpsoft here, I was desperete till I discovered the problem

Comment: Both chkal and I are from OCPsoft :) But glad to be of assistance!