# @PostConstruct method is not called

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, postconstruct

I wanted to use `@PostConstruct` to initialize a bean in my webapp but I can't get it to work.

I've recreated the problem in a new project and it still won't work.

Am I missing something obvious here? As far as I can tell my `init()` method fulfills all the requirements listed in `@PostConstruct` API reference.

`MyBean.java`:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean {
    @ManagedProperty(value="15")
    private int number = 10;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        number = 20;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

`number.xhtml`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
    <title>Simple JSF Facelets page</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    Number = #{myBean.number}
</h:body>

</html>
```

I would expect `Number = 20` but I get `Number = 15`.

Comment: This should work. Which server do you use? Which JSF version? You can add a print statement in your `init()` method to see if it gets called.

Comment: I'm using glassfish3.1.2 with Mojarra 2.1.6 (SNAPSHOT 20111206)

Comment: Strange. It seems the @ManagedProperty is recognized, but the  @ PostConstruct doesn't. Really strange.

Comment: SNAPSHOT might be the problem. You might want to avoid using it moving towards the [latest version](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.faces/). [Mojarra 2.2.5](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.5/) (or [api](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/com/sun/faces/jsf-api/2.2.5/), [impl](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/com/sun/faces/jsf-impl/2.2.5/)) is available today.

Comment: It's indeed a bug. You should avoid snapshot versions. By the way, GlassFish 4, and as mentionned above, Mojarra 2.2+ are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PostConstruct seems to be called before the injection with @ManagedProperty, assuming you have MyFaces 2.0, as they say [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605069/managedproperty-injected-after-postconstruct).

Make sure you are using Mojarra 2.1 because it should work.

You might try to debug to know if your init() method is called before the injection, or never called.

Comment: I think it's not getting called at all. When I comment out @ManagedProperty i get Number = 10, with private int number; (no initializer) i get Number = 0

Comment: What about [that](http://ovaraksin.blogspot.fr/2011/05/what-to-do-if-postconstruct-not-called.html)?

Comment: [That](http://ovaraksin.blogspot.fr/2011/05/what-to-do-if-postconstruct-not-called.html) did it! :-) Thanks

Answer (score -1):

By default, Spring will not aware of the @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy annotation. To enable it, you have to either register `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` or specify the `<context:annotation-config />` in bean configuration file.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you replace your class annotation ManagedBean by Named ?

Comment: Interesting things to read here : http://palkonyves.blogspot.fr/2012/12/ive-been-using-postconstruct-wrong-way.html